# Total power of CMBR

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

Could you check me on this: if I'm interested in total power (summed over all frequency) of CMBR absorbed by a black body in empty space, would that be proportional to the surface of BB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for a black body with emissivity of one, it is proportional to the area of the collector.

For any other object it is also proportional to the emissivity of the object.

Comment: Heh ... I was just about to ask about that division :) Thx, man!

Comment: I gotta stop sipping that Drano.

Comment: Didn't you get the def of emissivity backwards (1 equal perfectly efficient, 0 equals no radiation absorbed/emitted)? You were probably thinking of albedo, which runs the other way, but is typically used in relation to non thermal radiation.

Comment: You are correct. A perfect emitter, is 1.0 and would be dark black sooty looking. A perfectly shiny aluminum telescope mirror would have an emissivity of .04.

Comment: Thx. I have revised and extended my original answer. BTW - Some bikers paint their chrome flat black. The exhaust cools down a lot faster that way.

Comment: @Bill. I suspect white (or insert color of choice other than silver) would work as well. The reason is the thermal radiation is at much longer wavelength than visible, and most any nonmettalic coating will cover up the low emissivity metal. Albedo/emissivity in visible doesn't correlate well with the same thing in the IR. For instance green plants are pretty dark in visible, but good nearIR reflectors.